# Cucumber execution order in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cucumber

I have over 20 Cucumber features, when I execute test on my computer - test are running with alphabetic order, but when I execute test in remote Jenkins, order is always the same, but not in alphabetical order.
Do you know how execution order in jenkins is set?
I have problem with that because I have rerun class and I want to execute it at the end of tests

Answer (score 1):

First, As you can see in the [cucumber release notes](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), there is `--order` options for feature files.

Second, If you define feature files with in order under CucumberOptions like following it is also gonna run in order you define.

```
@Cucumber.Options(features={"automatedTestingServices.feature", "smoketest.feature"})
```

Third, And also you can give your execution order from terminal.(You didn't mentioned how you trigger and run your tests from jenkins)

```
cucumber login.feature order.feature account.feature
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation as you. But i create the order of execution from runner class in cucumber. In tags i identify the order of all my features like this

tags = {"@Login-Feature,@Account,@Transfer,@Check,@Log-Out"}

During the execution in Jenkins it takes this order, it doesn't create from alphabetic.

Comment: in my project i have 1 test runner for 1 feature, so its complicated to do it with this solution